# Несколько Spinner на одном Activity

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-spinner

Стоит задача реализовать поиск по сайту с большим количеством параметров (страна, город, категория продукта, тип продукта и т.д.). В суме есть восемь *Spinner* с разными наборами данных.

Вопрос в том, как реализовать адаптеры к этим Spinnerам так, что-бы не плодить код и было все красиво?

Работа происходит следующим образом:

Открывается страница поиска, мы делаем запрос к сети через *Retrofit2*, получаем список стран, сетаем в *Spinner*. После того, как юзер выбирает страну, мы делаем запрос к сети и получаем список областей и сетаем *Spinner* который ниже, а после как юзер выберет область, мы делаем запрос и получаем список категорий продукта и т.д.

Данные с сети приходят однотипные:

```
[{
"name": "Country1",
"value": 1
```

`}, {
    "name": "Country2",
    "value": 2
}]`

Comment: вы можете использовать один и тот же адаптр для всех спиннеров, зачем вам несколько, если нужно выводить данные одного внешнего вида

Comment: @pavlofff json однотипный, но данные разные.страна\область\марка\модель и т.д. если использовать один адаптер ко всем Spinnerм то когда мы подгружаем данные для второго Spinnerа сходя из того что   выбрано в первом то в первом данные тоже меняются. отсюда у меня и появился вопрос

Comment: нет, создавайте разные экземпляры одного и того же адаптера

Comment: @pavlofff а как быть с объектами? Country\State\Model которые нужно передавать в адаптер?